# Is it possible to change Blender's rotation axis?

Tags: interface, customization

In my quest to customize Blender so that it better fits my Source Filmmaker ass, I've gotten almost everything down except for the axis. X and Y are swapped between Blender and Source, however, the Z-axis being up is still consistent. The rotation axis however is not at all consistent, except for Flexion and Extention, which is Rotation X in both Blender and Source.

In Blender, Flexion and Extention (Rotating forward and backward like you're shaking your head yes) are on Rotation X, while they're rotation X in Source.

Abduction and Adduction (Rotating your arm to the side) are Rotation Y in Blender. Abduction and Adduction in Source however are Rotation Z.

Medial and Lateral Rotation (like shaking your head no) in Blender are Rotation Z, while in Source, it's Rotation Y.

I was wondering if the actual axis can be customized just like the controls. This would really help me out in the future, as SFM is my home pretty much with how comfortable I am with the controls.